# Can I apply an unique constraint on a field in both Temporal current table and history?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, temporal, temporal-tables

We have an authentication system that requires newly registered emails to have not been used before by any of our clients. Our email table is temporal, so between the current and historical tables, contains a list of emails that must be unique. If I could apply an unique constraint across both, it would validate any attempt to register a email that has already been used.

Is there a way to do this with Temporal tables?

Cannot put a constraint on a view of system-versioned tables.

Comment: Could you use a sproc to add emails. It could check?

Comment: @JamesCooke I was hoping to have integrity but if I can't this is the best solution.

Comment: Another option would be an INSERT trigger

Comment: @iamdave Yes. That would provide integrity. Thanks.

Comment: Just hit this thread when Googling same question. Nobody has yet answered the original yes/no question. My question about that question. If emails are already unique in both tables, wouldn't it be fine to just add the unique constraint to the main table and leave history table as is?

Comment: @ChrisHarrington An email could be deleted and re-added to the main table, not triggering a duplicate in the main table or history.

Comment: @cloudsafe It would trigger a duplicate if there were a unique constraint in the main table.